# Python vector transformation (normalize, scale, rotate etc.)

Tags: python, math, vector-graphics

I'm about to write my very own scaling, rotation, normalization functions in python. Is there a convenient way to avoid this? I found NumPy, but it kind-a seems like an overkill for my little 2D-needs.

Are there basic vector operations available in the std python libs?

Comment: *(joking)* Wait, you mean to say that numpy isn't part of the standard library?

Comment: seems not. What thinks make worse, I have the python 64bit version. There are only 'unofficial' binaries. U mean I should give NumPy a try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the standard in `numpy`. I wouldn't think of it as overkill, think of it as a very well written and tested library, even if you do just need a small portion of it. All the basic vector & matrix operations are implemented efficiently (falling back to C and Fortan) which makes it fast and memory efficient. Don't make your own, use numpy.

Comment: Performance-wise, don't expect too much from numpy if you work with mostly small arrays (e.g. vectors of length 2 or 3).  numpy shines with large arrays, but in some cases pure python can be faster when working with small vectors.

Comment: I only need it to draw a freakin' arrow in a UI. How bad can it be ;-)

Comment: BTW got it running. Thank you again.

Comment: Overkill written in C and Fortan is still overkill.